# Subtract 6 hours from an existing Date object java (midnight corner case)

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I'll be using the `Calendar` api for this. My primary concern is that

```
            Date birthDate = (...say Apr 20th 0300hrs)
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(birthDate);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -6);
            Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

Will `newDate` be Apr 19th 2100hrs (9 PM) ?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

After running the following code:

```
Date birthDate = (...say Apr 20th 0300hrs)
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(birthDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -6);
```

you are guaranteed that cal is set to six hours before 'Apr 20th 0300hrs', but not that it is set to 'Apr 19th 2100hrs'.

Comment: is there  a method to guarantee that the date is set to `Apr 19th 2100 hrs`?

Comment: `Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.APRIL, 19, 21, 0, 0);` - replace 2015 with whatever year you need.

Comment: @jambjo. hmm, that wont be scalable and requires maintenance. Let's say you're dealing with a huge database with hundreds of millions of birthdates that are not just in one year.

Comment: @bouncingHippo: It is not at all understandable what you are actually trying to achieve. If you need a Calendar set to April 19th, 21:00 in the same year as the `cal` you have built from `birthDate`, you can of course use `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)` to get the year instead of providing a hard coded value of 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Reference for calendar.add

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_add.htm

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter in Calendar's .add method is indeed the delta, or the change, so yes, this would subtract 6 hours.

read more here: 
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)